# How will i Stop all timers in a form vb.net

Tags: timer, foreach, vb.net-2010

I create dynamic form with timer(as a reminder) as a notification or alert form. i assign a name on each form.

so whenever it is updated.. i want to close or to disable the timer on that certain form so it will never show (as an alert).

the for each control to find timer doesn't work, i can't disable it.

```
 For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms


        If (f.Name = Label10.Text) Or (f.Name = "notification" & Label9.Text) Then

           Dim timer = Me.components.Components.OfType(Of IComponent)().Where(Function(p) p.[GetType]().FullName = "System.Windows.Forms.Timer").ToList()
              For Each cmd In timer
                  If Not cmd Is Nothing Then
                        Dim tmp As Timer = DirectCast(cmd, Timer)
                           tmp.Enabled = False
                           tmp.Stop()
                  End If
              Next

       End If

 Next
```

How will i change (Me.Components.Components) to f which is my form (f.Components.Components) please help me.

Comment: Please expand on "the for each control doesn't work". Also what are you trying to achieve with the If statement?

Comment: @andrew-buchan i want to determine if there is a timer within that form and stop or disable it. if statement is (if the form name is equal to label text) then find the timer and disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to loop through the timers on the form you need to first get a hold of them.  The controls collection does not contain any timer objects.  Timers were written in unmanaged C/C++ code by microsoft and only have little wrappers to support their API in .NET.

You can still access them though through a bit of finagling.  I have tested the following code and it does work with 1 timer on the form.  I have not tried it with more than 1 timer, but it should work.

```
Dim timer = Me.components.Components.OfType(Of IComponent)().Where(Function(p) p.[GetType]().FullName = "System.Windows.Forms.Timer").ToList()
    For Each cmd In timer
        If Not cmd Is Nothing Then
            Dim tmp As Timer = DirectCast(cmd, Timer)
            tmp.Enabled = False
            tmp.Stop()
        End If
    Next
```

Another version of this code could look like this with a bit of LINQ optimization going on:

```
Dim timer = Me.components.Components.OfType(Of IComponent)().Where(Function(ti) ti.GetType().FullName = "System.Windows.Forms.Timer").ToList()
    For Each tmp As Timer In (From cmd In timer Where Not cmd Is Nothing).Cast(Of Timer)()
        tmp.Enabled = False
        tmp.Stop()
    Next
```

Comment: @Winzengamot i always get this error null reference exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) i have print screen i don't know how to upload here

Comment: @winzengamot i think your code is correct. but i need to search the timer within (For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms) how will i do this?

Comment: How will i change (Me.Components.Components) to f which is my form (f.Components.Components) please help me.

Comment: Me.components is null ? Why