# Loop through all Timers

Tags: vb.net, loops, timer

I need to loop through all the timers on my form and check if they are enabled or not

I have found the following code: [How will i Stop all timers in a form vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070297/how-will-i-stop-all-timers-in-a-form-vb-net)

```
For Each c As Object In Me.components.Components
         If TypeOf c Is Timer Then
            CType(c, Timer).Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
```

However it gives me an error

```
 .Enabled is not a member of the system.threading.timer
```

How can I loop through all `Windows.forms.timers` ?

Comment: You need to post some code.  It looks like you are managing to cast the timer object incorrectly -- because the error indicates a type of `System.Threading.Timer` and it should be `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.  `System.Threading.Timer` does not expose any properties wheres `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` does and it has the `Enabled` property you are looking for.

Comment: In the link code you supplied it is casting to 'Timer'  Try replacing with 'Windows.Forms.Timer'

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think it would be that easy
If you write it as an answer I can mark it correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the cast you are doing, `CType(c, Timer)` is using an unqualified type name of `Timer` and is subsequently getting cast to `System.Threading.Timer` when it should be `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

If you fully qualify the type name then it should work the way that you expect:

```
For Each c As Object In Me.components.Components
   If TypeOf c Is Timer Then
       CType(c, System.Windows.Forms.Timer).Enabled = False
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than loop through every control, just loops through the timers like this.

```
For Each c As Timer In Me.components.Components
    If c.Enabled = False Then
        c.Enabled = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This still gives an error that enabled is not part of system.thread.timer

Comment: It ran fine on my pc.  Are you running the app as a service? Timers don't play nice in a service apparently

Comment: No its not part of a service, its a windows form application

Comment: Wierd. I'll have a look at Google

Comment: Hmm are you defining the timer programatically using system.threading.timer? How about using system.windows.forms.timer? Is that feasible?